# Primary key auto_increment not working on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, auto-increment

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    salary INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

My insert statement

```
INSERT INTO people
VALUES
('Austin', 65000),
('Josh', 100000),
('Pettea', 55000)
;
```

Comment: Can't reproduce anything with this insert query, that throws an error

Comment: @NicoHaase You must receive "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" error message. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a6c5c59241ae534b1964b827f7856f9). Maybe you have tried to reproduce the problem using some another DBMS?

Comment: @Akina exactly. So the strange question is: what does the OP mean by "not working"?

Comment: MYSQL allows you to override the auto_increment column (as long as the primary key is not duplicated) I suspect as a consequence of this you have to specify the the columns to be inserted rather than mysql assuming that the values supplied are for all columns other than the AI column.

Answer (score 2):

The columns amount (total columns amount in table structure while their list is skipped) must match the values amount strongly.

So either specify column names:

```
INSERT INTO people (first_name, salary)
VALUES
('Austin', 65000),
('Josh', 100000),
('Pettea', 55000);
```

or specify the value for each column:

```
INSERT INTO people
VALUES
(NULL, 'Austin', 65000),
(NULL, 'Josh', 100000),
(NULL, 'Pettea', 55000);
```

In the last code you may use zero value or DEFAULT keyword instead of NULL. Any of these 3 values causes new value generation.

PS. The former code is preferred - it does not need in any edition if the structure is altered.

PPS. I'd recommend to define autoincremented column datatype as UNSIGNED - this doubles the amount of possible autogenerated values twice.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
INSERT INTO people(first_name, salary)
VALUES
('Austin', 65000),
('Josh', 100000),
('Pettea', 55000);
```

try that.

Here's a working fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rW6QyPbyEMvZhcskipBpaX/0 
click "Run".

**Edit:**
I think I misread your comment: In this case you need to specify which column(s) you want to insert data. For now your query is trying to insert a two columns data value into a three columns table. `INSERT INTO people` is similar to `INSERT INTO people(id,first_name,salary)` so inserting two columns worth of data returns `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` error. It's acceptable if you do like this:

```
INSERT INTO people
VALUES
(1,'Austin', 65000),
(2,'Josh', 100000),
(3,'Pettea', 55000);
```

But you're making `id` column as `AUTO_INCREMENT` for a reason hence it's unnecessary to manually populate it.

Comment: So by default, it wouldn't automatically fill in id if I didn't specify the columns?

Comment: You don't need to specify the id column since it's auto_increment. It will self populate based on last running number. But if you still want to manually populate the id column you can. Refer to this example https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rW6QyPbyEMvZhcskipBpaX/1